# .keypress not working in browsers (except chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, keydown

I have an js that is not working in any browser except chrome? Is it maybe the .keydown function that makes trouble. There is a snippet of the code. It is made as an interactive video and when key is pressed a different layer of video is supposed to pop up.

```
    var videos = document.querySelectorAll("video");
var promises = Promise.all(Array.prototype.slice.call(videos).map(function(video) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      video.addEventListener("canplaythrough", resolve);
      video.addEventListener("error", reject);
    })
  }))
  .then(function() {
    videos.forEach(function(video) {
      video.play();
    });
    videos[2].style.display = "none";
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var key = e.key;
      if (key === "b" || key === "B") {
        videos[2].style.display = "block";
        videos[1].style.display = "none";
        videos[0].style.display = "none";
      }
    });
    videos[1].style.display = "none";
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var key = e.key;
      if (key === "a" || key === "A") {
        videos[2].style.display = "none";
        videos[1].style.display = "block";
        videos[0].style.display = "none";
      }
    });
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      videos[2].style.display = "none";
      videos[1].style.display = "none";
      videos[0].style.display = "block";
    });
    window.focus();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Browser doesn't give any errors. And i don't know where to go on from here. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <body bgcolor="#00">
    <center><img src="head.png" alt="Head"></center>
  </head>
 <style>
 video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12vw;
}
.full-frame {
    width:75%%;
    height:75%
}
</style>
<br><br>
<div id="video"; overflow: hidden">
   <video src="1.mov" style="width: 75%; height: 75%;" autoplay loop></video>
    <video src="2.mov" style="width: 75%; height: 75%;" autoplay loop></video>
   <video src="3.mov" style="width: 75%; height: 75%;" autoplay loop></video>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> document.body.addEventListener()

instead of document.addEventListener()

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. Should i replace anything else?

Comment: I think problem is with your styles and not with script

Comment: <style>
 video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12vw;
}
.full-frame {
 width:75%%;
 height:75%
}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

As I know, keyboard related events are only fires when the element has focus. So basically you need give the focus to work correctly. What about attaching event on window object?

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => console.log(e.keyCode))
```

I just checked on chrome and FF, both were worked.

Comment: Hi! I attached the line. Now the browser records the key press. But videos don't change. Is it possible that the guy who coded this messed something up in html? I added the code to the original poste.